# A geometric sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $z_0=3$ and $ z_{n+1}=\dfrac{2}{z_n +1} $ and $t_n=\dfrac{z_n-1}{z_n+2}$ prove that $t_n$ is a geometric sequence find its general form.

Comment: Do you substitute $t_n$, $t_{n+1}$ to delete $z$'s from general term?

Comment: Help me @MyGlasses

Comment: Try $$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}$$.

Comment: I've found nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_{n}}=t_{n+1}\frac{1}{t_{n}}=
\frac{z_{n+1}-1}{z_{n+1}+2}\frac{z_{n}+2}{z_{n}-1}=
\frac{\frac{2}{z_{n}+1}-1}{\frac{2}{z_{n}+1}+2}\frac{z_{n}+2}{z_{n}-1}=
\frac{-(z_{n}-1)}{2(z_{n}+2)}\times\frac{z_{n}+2}{z_{n}-1}=
-\frac12
$$
which is a geometric sequence $\displaystyle t_0=\frac25$.

Answer (score 0):

Try harder:

$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac{z_{n+1}-1}{z_{n+1}+2}\cdot\frac{z_n+2}{z_n-1}=\frac{\frac2{z_n+1}-1}{\frac2{z_n+1}+2}\cdot\frac{z_n+2}{z_n-1}=$$

$$=\frac{1-z_n}{2(z_n+2)}\cdot\frac{z_n+2}{z_n-1}=\ldots$$